# What is the correct way to allocate and pass a string?

Tags: c, windows

I have a string, for which i allocate memory. After that, i pass this string to another function, and then from the second function i pass it to a third function. The problem is, that after the tird function completes, i can access/use the variable. But after the second function completes, i can't access it's value in the first function. So obviously i'm doing somethin wrong, but i don't what. 
Could someone please help me? 
Of course if anyone has better idee, how i should do what i want, i would also appreciate it.
My code so far:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100

void Func1()
{
   char *Test = NULL;
   Test = ( char * )malloc( MAX_SIZE*sizeof( char ) );
   if ( Test == NULL )
   {
      return;
   }

   Func2( Test );

   if ( Test!= NULL ) free( Test);
}

void Func2(char *string)
{
    Func3( &string);
}

void Func3( char **string)
{
    if (Len > MAX_SZIE )
    {
         char *tmp = NULL;
         tmp = ( char * )realloc( *string, Len + 1 );
         if ( !tmp )
         {
               return;
         }
         *string = tmp;
         memset( *string, 0, sizeof( *string ) );
    }
    memcpy( *string, SomeOtherString, Len );
    free( SomeOtherString );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
Updated the function, with the current code i have now:

```
bool __stdcall Function( DataToSendBack *DataArray )
{
char *Result = NULL;
char InString[ MAX_SIZE ] = { 0 };
int DataLen = 0;
bool bRetVal = false;

__try
{
    Result = ( char * )malloc( MAX_SIZE );
    if ( Result == NULL )
    {
        __leave;
    }

    memset( InString, 0, sizeof( InString ) );
    memset( Result, 0, sizeof( Result ) );

    memcpy( InString, DataArray->StringIn, strlen( DataArray->StringIn ) );

    Result = GetInfo( InString, Result, &DataLen );
    if ( Result == NULL )
             {
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"error",NULL,NULL);
                    __leave;
             }

    if ( strlen( ErrorMsg ) > 0 ) strcpy( DataArray->ErrorMessage, ErrorMsg );

    if ( DataArray->RequiredSize < DataLen )
    {
        DataArray->RequiredSize = DataLen;
        strcpy( DataArray->ErrorMessage, ErrorMsg );
        __leave;
    }

    DataArray->Result = _strdup( Result );
    bRetVal = true;
}
__finally
{
    if ( Result != NULL ) free( Result );
}

return bRetVal;

}

char * GetInfo( char *String, char *Result, int *DataLen )
{
  bool bRetVal = false;

__try
{
    if ( DoStuff( String, &Result, DataLen ) )
    {
        bRetVal = true;
    }
}
__finally
{
    // free other things
}

return Result;
}

 bool DoStuff( char *MyString, char **Result, int *DataLen )
 {
__try
{
    //Call function which returns dwsize
    *DataLen = dwSize * 2;
            OtherString = SomFunction();
    if ( strlen( OtherString ) > MAX_SIZE )
    {
        char *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = ( char * )realloc( *Result, strlen( OtherString ) );
        if ( !tmp )
        {
            __leave;
        }
        *Result = tmp;
        memset( *Result, 0, sizeof( *Result ) );
    }

    memcpy( *Result, OtherString, strlen( OtherString ) );

    free( OtherString );

    bretVal = true;
}
__finally
{
    // free other things
}

return bretVal;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: `if ( Result == NULL )`... where is `Result` declared???

Comment: Sorry, Result is Test.

Comment: Func3 is changing the string. Why would you expect to be able to access it after it's been mucked with?

Comment: Please don't do either of `( char * )malloc`, `sizeof( char )` or `if ( Test!= NULL ) free( Test);`, each of them are redundant and hurt code readability. So, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`; `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and `free(NULL)` is a safe no-op.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: ok, but how should i do it the correct way?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: If i don't cast it i get error `cannot convert from void* to char*`

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to accompish. I can't tell what that is from this code. What do you want it to do?

Comment: @kampi then change your compiler. The conversion from `void *` to (and from) any other (appropriately-qualified) object pointer type is implicit and well-defined.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Basicly i need the string from Func3 in Func1.

Comment: Remember that the memory you need to allocate (and copy) with strings is **one byte more** than the `strlen` of the string, due to the extra zero byte appended as terminator. Otherwise you risk asking, for example, `_strdup` to duplicate an unterminated, potentially crashingly long string.

Comment: @Iserni: I corrected that mistake, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Func3() modifies the pointer that Func1() allocated. You need to pass it back to Func1():

```
void Func1()
{
   char *Test = NULL;
   if (NULL == (Test = malloc(MAX_SIZE) ) {
      // Handle case of OOM error
      return;
   }

   // Func2 may modify Test
   Test = Func2( Test );

   if (NULL == Test) {
       // Handle case of error in Func3
   }
   free(Test); // Test = NULL;
}

/**
 * Reads and modifies (through a call to Func3) a pointer to string
 */
char * Func2(char *string)
{
    Func3( &string);
    return string;
}
```

Also, in Func3(), you need to:

```
memset( *string, 0, Len + 1 );
```

to zero the whole string.

But actually you're writing `OtherString` into `*string`, so zeroing all those bytes, as WhozCraig points out, is unnecessary. What you should really do is make sure you have enough space, and zero the one byte *immediately after* the string, **if** it is necessary. So that would be

```
strncpy(*string, OtherString, Len);
(*string)[Len] = 0x0;
```

or more efficiently (since `strncpy` will zero whatever comes after the copy of OtherString, up to Len bytes)

```
size_t new_len = strlen(OtherString);
if (new_len <= Len) {
    // Copy, including last zero
    memcpy(*string, OtherString, new_len+1);
} else {
    // Copy Len bytes, from 0 to Len-1
    memcpy(*string, OtherString, Len);
    // Zero last byte to make it a valid C string
    (*string)[Len] = 0x0;
}
```

or
    size_t new_len = min(Len, strlen(OtherString));
    memcpy(*string, OtherString, new_len);
    // Zero last byte to make it a valid C string
    (*string)[new_len] = 0x0;

## Update

For testing purposes, this is the Func3() I used:

```
#define OtherString     "To be or not to be, that is the question\n"
#define Len             10240
#define min(a,b)        (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))

void Func3( char **string)
{
     char *tmp = realloc( *string, Len+1);
     if (NULL == tmp)
     {
           return;
     }
     *string = tmp;
     size_t new_len = strlen(OtherString);
     new_len        = min(Len, new_len);
     memcpy(*string, OtherString, new_len);
     // Zero last byte to make it a valid C string
     (*string)[new_len] = 0x0;
}
```

In one case it returns "To be or not to be", in the other (Len=16) it returns "To be or not to ", as expected.

Comment: Regarding the latter `memset`, it is pointless to fill `Len+1` slots with zero when only one of them is important; the last one. `(*string)[Len] = 0;` after the `memcpy` will suffice.

Comment: Good catch, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: So bayicly you just edited, that Func2 should return a char *, right? Unfortunately i'm getting the following error: "Stack around the variable 'Test' was corrupted"

Comment: No, there are some other modifications. I ran the code through `valgrind` after compiling with `-Wextra -Wall`, and got no errors. Maybe there's some other problem? Can you supply a self-contained test case?

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. All i see, the changes you made are: Func2 returns a char*, not a void, and in Func1 you changed the malloc. So far so good. If i debug the application, Func2 completes fine, after that it will be freed, but then at the last `}` i get the error.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is this could have to do with the value of `Len`. If it's larger than `strlen(OtherString)` you might get an invalid read. I used two arbitrary values of 16 and 10240, and "To be or not to be, that is the question" as OtherString. All I can say is, it worked. Inspect Test's value after Func2 returns.

Comment: Suggestion: in `func3` call it `p_string` or in fact anything besides `string`.  This helps to make the code readable, it is confusing to have `string` in one part of the code have a different level of indirection to `string` in another part of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! As it turned out, i had another mistake, and that had an effect at this code snippet. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're `realloc()`ating the string in `Func3()`. However, the new, potentially modified pointer is never returned to `Func1()`, because `Func2()` takes the pointer by value, not by pointer. Hence, you will access a potentially deallocated memory region.

The solution: depending on what you need, you might possibly want to pass the original string by pointer to `Func2()` (and perhaps to `Func1()`) as well.

Comment: Could you maybe please correct my code? I can't get it to work :(